# Mathematica 12.2 on Windows 7

Tags: windows, compatibility, installation, version-12.2

The Mathematica 12.3 setup.exe installer will not run on Windows 7, due to the operating system not being supported by that Mathematica version.  Although Mathematica 12.2 also does not support Windows 7, the installer will run.

Will Mathematica 12.2 work fine on Windows 7, even though it is not officially supported?  I was thinking about asking Wolfram if they could downgrade my Mathematica purchase to 12.1, which officially supports Windows 7, but I'm wondering if 12.2 will work just as well.

Also, what is the purpose of the Windows 7 Platform Update (that appears in the 12.1 system requirements) in relation to Mathematica?  Do I need to make sure I have this Windows Update before installing Mathematica 12.1, 12.2 etc., or is it only necessary for a niche feature of Mathematica which can be addressed during later troubleshooting?

Comment: Interesting questions but probably not within the scope of this site.

Comment: Given than I did successfully run 12.2 on Windows 7 64 bit (6.1, build 7601), I'm wondering if there would still be a way to get 12.3 installed and running on Windows 7.

Comment: No.  The FrontEnd will not start if the OS does not meet the requirements.

Comment: @user3257842 you can take front-end from 12.2 and use it with 12.3. It is running, but very laggy (typing in text, scrolling or resizing windows is too slow).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

12.2 should run on Windows 7 (assuming it is fully updated).  It's not supported, so Tech Support will only go so far if you encounter issues.

As for not having the Platform Update installed, the FrontEnd should complain at startup about failing to initialize a component.