# Can Mathematica 13 be installed and run on Windows 7 x64?

Tags: windows, compatibility, version-13

Can *Mathematica* 13 be installed and run on Windows 7 x64? Can two versions (11.3 and 13) be installed in the same Windows system?

Comment: See [249317](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/249317/mathematica-12-2-on-windows-7). Regarding Mma13, the systems requirements [page](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/system-requirements.html) says that the `The minimum version supported is version 1709` which is Win10.

Comment: Thank you! @Syed

Comment: I use v12.2.0 Win7-x64 which is the last possible upgrade on my old machine.

Answer (score 4):

> Can *Mathematica* 13 be installed and run on Windows 7 x64?

No, it can not. The last *Mathematica* version that can work on Windows 7 is version 12.2. Citing [John Fultz (Wolfram Research, Inc.)](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2431430):

> Microsoft ended support for Windows 7 in
> 2020. We continued to support it with our latest releases until the 12.2 release in December, 2020. Although 12.2 didn't officially support Windows 7, it didn't actively break anything (that we knew
> of), but 12.3, released in May of 2021, did.
>
> The decision to drop support wasn't arbitrary. We had long delayed a
> significant update to our 2D rendering and font rendering subsystems
> under Windows. We need to replace the legacy GDI-based systems with
> modern DirectWrite-based systems. DirectWrite first shipped with
> Windows 7, but it wasn't yet in a fully baked state in that initial
> release. We did as much as we could by elevating the minimum OS to
> Windows 7 Platform Update in 12.0. But we couldn't completely
> eradicate our GDI usage without using DirectWrite as it stood in
> Windows 8.1 (which basically nobody uses anymore, so we just went to
> Windows 10).
>
> Eradicating GDI was important not only to allow new feature
> development, but because some of our GDI usage was being actively
> flagged by some AV/security software in the wild. This had been
> reported to us dozens, if not hundreds of times, so fixing it was a
> huge priority. Our usage of GDI was perfectly supported by Microsoft,
> and caused no security problems. But the world changed around us, and
> some modern security vendors were willing to conclude that anyone
> using certain GDI techniques posed a potential threat, without the
> need to verify whether the threat was real.
>
> And, yes, Microsoft's dropping support, and feedback from our sales
> and support teams made it seem like the sting wouldn't be too bad as
> well. I'm certainly very sorry that this affects you the way it has,
> but I'm also extremely happy that we can tell people who were having
> their usage of our products blocked by their security software that
> they can now update rather than crafting security exceptions (an
> option which, rightly, some folks weren't so happy with). And this
> unblocks some of our development on high performance drawing, better
> HiDpi support, and support of fast-evolving font technology.

---

> Can the two versions (V11.3 and V13) be installed in the same Windows system?

Yes, I have versions 12.3.1 and 13.0.0 both installed and run on Windows 10 x64.

But be aware of the [incompatible changes](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/IncompatibleChanges.html#447496873) listed in the official Documentation:

> - The default typesetting of colors evaluated and saved in a 13.0 kernel will not display properly if the notebook is opened in a front end before 12.2.
> - Notebooks and preference files now save associations using the `<||>` syntax rather than the `Association` syntax. Notebook front ends before 10.0 will report syntax errors. This can make it difficult to run such front ends on the same system as 13.0 because, by default, the old and new FEs will share the same automatically managed preferences file in `$UserBaseDirectory/FrontEnd/init.m`. If this is an issue, you can force the usage of versioned preferences files by evaluating: `CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, VersionedPreferences]=True`.

This means that it is strongly recommended at least to set the following option:

[image: screesnhot]

Comment: Thank you very much! @Alexey Popkov